# Navigation Title background image not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

[This my simulator screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZp7q.png) 
    import UIKit

```
class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addCustomNavigationBarToView()


}
```

// This is my custom navigation bar Function

```
    func addCustomNavigationBarToView(){
```

// Here i create a navigationBar variable

```
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100))
        let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "BarBa.jpg")          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage,for: .default)
```

//i was created navigation item variable and setup an image

```
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 90 ))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    // Create left and right button for navigation item
        let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector(("saveButtonClicked:")))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        //tapping the menu button work
 // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addCustomNavigationBarToView function you have written wrong code:

Your TableViewController don't have any NavigationBar but you are currently setting background Image to self.navigationController.navigationBar :

```
   {   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage,for: .default)
   }
```

You need to change your code to:

```
{
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage,for: .default)
}
```